# volume and mute buttons not working on Ubuntu

Tags: pulseaudio, pipewire

It has been days since my volume buttons and the mute button work correctly. I have been trying everything related to pulse audio that could have caused this. Reinstalling, resetting my volume and mute keys, and doing an alsa force reload but nothing works.

Comment: Please write it in question/answer format. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1435784/edit) the question as a "question", and post the solution as an answer

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have made the change

Answer (score 2):

I was messing around with the audio system and had installed various packages to play the audio. I had installed so many that I lost track of them. after a few days, I noticed my audio buttons would not respond. I started to think what are the packages that may have caused this issue. I noticed I had pulse audio installed and so I tried reinstalling it safely by following a proper guideline this time but nothing seemed to work when I had almost given up I thought, wait! I should try tracing back the list of packages I downloaded I used the following code for it ...

`grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log`

after this step, I noticed that I had pipewire-pulse which actually caused the issue (I googled and learned a few things). The following are the codes I used to resolve

`sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio`

`systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager`

and it worked!

Ps: this post is for me when I find myself stuck in the future but if it helps somebody I would love that :)

Comment: Do you have a "/usr/share/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf" file? It should take care of the pulse/pipewire connection. Else this looks like bug which you might report on launchpad..